# Код на Python в скрипт на Bash

Tags: python, bash

У меня есть скрипт на баше:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Переменная BAM_FILE будет содержать список всех bam-файлов в текущей директории
BAM_FILE=$(ls *.bam)

for FILE in ${BAM_FILE}; do

    # Имя файла без расширения
    NAME=$(basename ${FILE} .bam)

    # Получаем fastq 1 и 2
    samtools fastq -1 ${NAME}_R1.fastq -2 ${NAME}_R2.fastq ${NAME}_hlareg.bam
```

Далее часть кода выполняется на Python. Как мне интегрировать его в скрипт? Я делаю вот так, но output-файлы на создаются:

```bash
python -c '
import sys

def sync_fastq_files():
    file1 = "${NAME}_R1.fastq"
    file2 = "${NAME}_R2.fastq"
    output_file1 = "${NAME}_R1_sync.fastq"
    output_file2 = "${NAME}_R2_sync.fastq"

    with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2, \
          open(output_file1, "w") as out1, open(output_file2, "w") as out2:
        while True: 
    ...... 
'
```

Отдельно код на питоне работает, когда вместо file1, file2, output_file1, output_file2 прописать название самих файлов (например, тестовых двух файлов), но мне нужно, чтобы код работал для всех файлов в директории, содержащих ${NAME} в названии.

Comment: Напрашивается предложение полностью уйти от баша в питон с такой задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Не проверял, но думаю так:

```
python -c '
import os, sys

def sync_fastq_files():
    name = os.environ["NAME"]
    file1 = f"{name}_R1.fastq"
    file2 = f"{name}_R2.fastq"
    output_file1 = f"{name}_R1_sync.fastq"
    output_file2 = f"{name}_R2_sync.fastq"

    with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2, \
          open(output_file1, "w") as out1, open(output_file2, "w") as out2:
        while True: 
    ...... 
'
```

Comment: NAME не экспотирована, не проверял но думаю не сработает)

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете одинарные кавычки `'...'` для вставки кода на Python поэтому ваши переменные из bash'а не работают. Используйте двойные `"..."` а внутри одинарные или используйте heredoc конструкцию:

```
python -c << EOF
...
EOF
```

Comment: Спасибо! А с переменными все нормально? Можно их оставить в таком виде внутри питоновского кода?

Comment: Не вижу проблем. Внутри питоновского кода они уже не будут переменными там будет только значение.

Answer (score 1):

можно сразу запустить в  Bash код командой 
`python main.py`

А можно 
`python -c "print('hello world')"`